# Simple Bootstrap/Foundation Padding Layout Issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

So I always encounter this issue when doing layouts with Bootstrap/Foundation or similar.

Say I have a `.row` and inside it I have two columns, on the left column I have something like an H1 which is big and has padding. In the right column I have a simple text  tag. What will happen when I do this is the H1 will look fine and vertically centered in the `.row` but the `<a>` because it's small will move to the top of the `.row` and it will look off. To correct this I could add `margin-top` to the  tag but then when I resize the browser window to a different breakpoint the `margin-top` will mess up the responsive layout. How do you work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best choice would be to use margins, but then add some fine grain control by using media queries (simply use the default media queries that Twitter Bootstrap and Foundation use) to change the look and feel.
Something like normalise.css can be used to reset some styling, but I think in your case there is always going to be some difference between and H1 tag and an a tag etc...